# How can I recursively copy entire directories and exclude specific files with extention "min.min.js"

Tags: bash, shell

I need help with bash command that recursively cp all the file or subdirectory inside but also exclude some specific file like "*.min.min.js".

Comment: You may want to explain what you have tried so far.  Alternatively superuser.stackexchange.com may also be a better place to ask.

Comment: `find \! -name '*.min.min.js' -exec cp {} ... \;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use rsync:

```
rsync -av --exclude '*min.min.js' parent_dir dest_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use tar

`tar c --exclude "*.min.min.js" source_dir | tar -C /destination xv`